# Delete row in sql?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-delete

In this AddPatient.cs  I can't delete the entire row but when this action is performed in C# through delete button action  it's not working therefore I need help.

```
    private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       if (pno.Text != "" || pname.Text != "" || age.Text != "" || sex.Text != "" || add.Text != "" || city.Text != "" || phone.Text != "" || edate.Text != ""
            || dname.Text != "" || dig.Text != "" || dpname.Text != "")
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = 
                "delete from PatientDetails where PatientNumber= '" + pno.Text + "' and PatientName='" + pname.Text + "' and Age='" + age.Text + "' and Sex ='" + sex.Text + "' and PatientAddress='" + add.Text + "' and City='" + city.Text + "' and PhoneNumber='" + phone.Text + "' and EntryDate='" + edate.Text + "' and DoctorName='" + dname.Text + "' and Diagnosis='" + dig.Text + "' and  DepartmentName='" + dpname.Text + "'";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Clone();
                cn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted Successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

             }


    }
```

Comment: Please define "not working". Is it an error or is the row not deleted?

Comment: Define **(1)** the actual database you're using, and **(2)** what the *not working* really means - do you get an error? If so, *what* error?? Does it just not do anything? And please: use **parametrized queries** and don't concatenate together your SQL like this!!

Comment: ` cmd.Clone();` ??? and this sql does not execute. read some tutorial how to write sql, pls

Comment: When I'm clicking delete it's not working!

Answer (score 4):

The separator in a `where` clause is `and` or `or`, not `,`:

```
           "delete from PatientDetails where PatientNumber= '" + pno.Text + "' and PatientName='" + pname.Text + "' and Age='" + age.Text + "' and Sex ='" + sex.Text + "' and PatientAddress='" + add.Text + "' and City='" + city.Text + "' and PhoneNumber='" + phone.Text + "' and EntryDate='" + edate.Text + "' and DoctorName='" + dname.Text + "' and Diagnosis='" + dig.Text + "' and  DepartmentName='" + dpname.Text + "'";
```

However, you should really be deleting by id not by a long list of columns.

Also, consider using parameterized queries.  Direct inclusion of user input into strings not only poses a SQL injection hazard, but it can break the system.  For instance, if one of the names is "O'Conner".

Comment: @AdeesananSiva . . . Edit your question and print out the query *after* the variable substitution.  The error will probably be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

ever heard of primary key ? ever heard of Entity framework or nhibernate ?

refrain from manual stuff like that !